# How can I create automatic commits?

Tags: git

I have a git directory in `root`.

I have files being saved here.

```
/root/web/source/favcions
```

I need a way to automatically add and commit them.

Either based on time, based on a bash script, or based on git hooks

I will be pulling/pushing to this git repo so is there a `pre-pull` hook I could use?

I'm looking here:
https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks

```
#!/bin/sh
# I'm in my bare repo hooks - post_update
cd repo_a
git add -A .
git commit -m "test"
cd repo_b

git pull x
git push y
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're on Linux, [gitwatch](https://github.com/nevik/gitwatch) might be what you're looking for. It is:

> A bash script to watch a file or folder and commit changes to a git repo.

Comment: I thought about it more and b.c. the files might change to often, I'm just going to update on code updates.

Answer (score 2):

Why so complicated? Use the bash and write the commands after each other.

```
git add -A;git commit -m "Commit from server";git push origin master
```

A hook is if you commit something to git to work with the new data. But that isn't working with file changes. That is not the concept of git by the way. Git is to track files with code. So normally you have to ignore changing files on your server.

There is a script gitwatch you could try but its not really good to have a lot of commits with log entries in your repo.

Comment: Thanks.  I put my solution in the question can you tell me what you think.  I think it is the same as yours but I you have to pull the changes from the user before pushing code updates.  Git requires this pull before a push.